# ActionMode: MultiChoiceListener does not highlight the first item

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

I have this in my Fragment

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new PlayerMultiChoiceListener(getListView(), getBaseActivity()));
        ...    
    }
```

and this is the implementation

```
public abstract class PlayerMultiChoiceListener implements MultiChoiceModeListener {

    protected final ListView listView;
    protected final BaseActivity activity;
    protected final PlayerManager playerManager;

    public AbstractMultiChoiceListener(ListView listView, BaseActivity activity) {
        this.listView = listView;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.playerManager = PlayerManager.getInstance(activity);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        mode.setTitle(listView.getCheckedItemCount() + activity.getString(R.string.action_mode_title_selected));
        mode.getMenu().clear();
        if (listView.getCheckedItemCount() > 1) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_actionmode, mode.getMenu());
        } else {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_actionmode_one_selected, mode.getMenu());
        }
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(
                checked ? android.R.color.holo_blue_light : android.R.color.transparent);
    }

}
```

The first selected item (the one I longpress on to enter the ActionMode) is not highlighted by the `holo_blue_light`. It's marked as checked and the code that changes the background is executed but with no effect. Next selected items are hightlighted just fine. Any ideas?